# How to stop safari (on ipad) from firing hover event?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ipad

I have a button that is fixed on my page and when you start to scroll it appears. I noticed on ipad safari I have to click this button twice to fire the click event once.

After searching around I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32706770/130015) sure enough when I commented out my "display:none" on the button it works.

How can I achieve having it hidden and then changing it to "display:block" without getting this double click issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css position instead to place it off screen:

```
.hide {
   position: absolute;
   left: -999em;
}
```

You could also try the visibility property

```
.hide {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```

[w3c example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

Comment: thanks, maybe it is not the hidden that is the cause, I am still getting the same thing with your suggestions.

Comment: @chobo2 what about changing the buttons opacity? opacity: 0     Even moving the button off screen didn't work?