# jquery image hover on tablet

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I'm trying to incorporate a hover image rotating function on a website used on tablet. Unfortunately I am a bit lost on how to solve the last pieces of the puzzle. Anyone able to help? THe script below rotates an images when hovering and adds an additional text box.

```
jquery:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".1").hover(
function(){$("#Information-Seawater").show();},
function(){$("#Information-Seawater").hide()});

});

jQuery(function(){
     $(".1").hover(
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("-Icon","-Image");},
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("-Image","-Icon");
     });
});
```

style:

```
#Information-Seawater {
    display: none;
      top: 650px;
      margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:60%; 
    font-family: Consolas;
    background: #00bbe4;
    border: 2px solid black;
    COLOR: #006080; 
  }
```

html:

```
<td class="style6" style="height: 77px; width: 140px"><a href="Http://"><img `id="1" height="147" src="website-%20images/Seawater-Icon.jpg" alt="" class="1" width="140"></a></td>`

<div id="Information-Seawater">
<span class="Information-Header">text<br /></span>
text
<br />
</div>
```

The above script works well on a pc, but not on a tablet. I hope someone is able to help me to incorporate the above with the function like the ones below, where on a tablet an images needs to be clicked once before hovering kicks in.

http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/s9rB4/

or

[Jquery hover function and click through on tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445086/jquery-hover-function-and-click-through-on-tablet)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hover on a tablet because no event happens until you touch the screen at which point it is a click. Try detecting when it is a tablet and bind a click event instead of a hover.